# What is the difference between webgl and opengl es?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I found webgl and opengl es for 3d games browser while searching on the internet. But I don't understand what is the difference between the two kinds of api.

Answer (score 5):

WebGL is based on OpenGL-ES, but with the difference that it is written with a HTML5 Canvas being the container for a GL context. Also it defines a new set of JavaScript functions available through a GL context enabled Canvas DOM.

OpenGL-ES is a specification for a plattform independent rendering API. The browser and HTML5 canvas *is* a plattform, and WebGL is a derivation of OpenGL-ES-2 for this plattform.